# "Ждёшь День знаний" или "Ждёшь Дня знаний"?

Tags: падежи, управление

Как сказать правильнее: "Ты ждёшь День знаний" или "Ты ждёшь Дня знаний"?

Answer (score 2):

Это **ждательный падеж**, если вернуться к тем временам, когда в правилах русского языка было больше шести падежей (их в реальности и сейчас больше, но в правилах - шесть! :) ).
В современном языке ждательный падеж — явление довольно сложное и странное. **Ждать (бояться, остерегаться, стесняться)** мы можем кого-то или чего-то, то есть, будто бы, должны использовать родительный падеж с этими глаголами. Однако порой вместо родительного падежа вдруг имеет место винительный. Например, мы ждём (кого? чего?) письма, но (кого? что?) маму. А, наоборот, «ждать письмо» или «ждать мамы» — как-то не по-русски (особенно, второе). (Я, кстати, не знаю, изучаются ли сейчас дополнительные падежи в вузах филологами, мои сестры в 80–х изучали.)
Разумеется, можно считать, что никакого ждательного падежа нет, просто с глаголом ждать (и его собратьями) можно использовать и родительный, и винительный падежи. Но, на мой взгляд, проще эти формы допустимыми не признавать, и ждательный падеж всё же существует, причём для одушевленных объектов будет использоваться форма винительного падежа, а для неодушевленных  правильнее будет форма родительного.
Так что, если руководствоваться этими соображениями, более правильна фраза **"Ты ждёшь Дня знаний"**.